# Turn on "Create Dashboard Folders" permission

Tags: dashboard, folder

I am not able to create a new dashboard folder using my standard user. I have been trying to find the Create Dashboard Folders permission, which (according to documentation)should be in the profile permissions. Unfortunately I cannot find this permission anywhere.
How do I allow my standard user to create a dashboard folder?

Rgds, Lily

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but only in Lightning Experience. The only way to resolve it was to quickly switch back to classic, create the Dashboard folder there, and switch to Lightning again. Then it's available for your dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

To create, edit, and delete public dashboard folders:   “Manage Dashboards” AND “View All Data”

[Help Article](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_and_editing_folders.htm)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Customize Application permission allow you to create a dashboard folder For standard user profile

Answer (score 0):

There are in System Permissions, then seek for Permission Name: "Create Dashboard Folders"

Answer (score 0):

Lightning Experience Note: In order to create Report or Dashboard folders in Lightning, Enhanced Folder Sharing for Reports and Dashboards must be enabled in Classic by your administrator. You can find out the steps to enable this setting at:
https://dreamevent.secure.force.com/articleView?id=000332029&type=1&mode=1